# How to use promisify() with the spawn() function for the 'child_process'?

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I have the following code example, and I have now ideas on how to resolve this using `utils.promisify();` ONLY! Not Promise!

```
const spawn = child_process.spawn('docker', ['--version']);

spawn.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
   process.stdout.write(data);
});

spawn.on('error', () => {
   process.stderr.write(error);
   process.exit(1);
});
```

The second code example works fine.

```
const promisifiedExecFile = promisify(child_process.execFile);

async function test() {
  const version = await promisifiedExecFile('docker', ['--version']);
  console.log(version);
}

test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js' built-in util package has a `promisify()` function that converts callback-based functions to promise-based functions. This lets you use promise chaining and async/await with callback-based APIs.

I think that we can't use the `promisify()` with the `spawn()` function.
For example we can use `promisify()` with `execFile()` instead of `spawn()`:

```
async asyncExecFile(tool) {
        const execFile = util.promisify(child_process.execFile);

        return await execFile(tool, ['--version'])
            .catch(() => {
                this.printError(`The "${tool}" don't exist in the current environment. \n`);
                process.exit(0);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't quickly find out why the `promisify` function does now work properly with the `spawn` function. But you can create your own promisify function like this:

`TS`

```
import { spawn as spwn } from 'child_process';

const spawn = (
  cmd: string,
  args: ReadonlyArray<string>,
) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const cp = spwn(cmd, args);
  const error: string[] = [];
  const stdout: string[] = [];
  cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    stdout.push(data.toString());
  });

  cp.on('error', (e) => {
    error.push(e.toString());
  });

  cp.on('close', () => {
    if (error.length) reject(error.join(''));
    else resolve(stdout.join(''));
  });
});

(async () => {
  try {
    const stdOut = await spawn('docker', ['--version']);
    console.log('stdOut: ', stdOut);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
})();
```

`JS`

```js
const { spawn: spwn } = require('child_process');

const spawn = (
  cmd,
  args,
) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const cp = spwn(cmd, args);
  const error = [];
  const stdout = [];
  cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    stdout.push(data.toString());
  });

  cp.on('error', (e) => {
    error.push(e.toString());
  });

  cp.on('close', () => {
    if (error.length) reject(error.join(''));
    else resolve(stdout.join(''));
  });
});

(async () => {
  try {
    const stdOut = await spawn('docker', ['--version']);
    console.log('stdOut: ', stdOut);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
})();
```

Comment: It is OK to use Promise, but how to use `util.promisify()`

Comment: `util.promisify()` assumes a call signature with the last argument being an error callback. Which was a majority of asynchronous procedures in NodeJS pre-promises, but not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because there is nothing to `promisify`. `promisify` works on functions where it takes a callback and `spawn` does not take a callback.

You use `spawn` by taking the returned `ChildProcess` then adding listeners to the `ChildProcess`' readable streams (`stdout`, `stderr`, `stdio`...)

Omar Omeiri's answer is similar to [how `execFile` works inside node itself](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/child_process.js#L326), so you can just use the promisified `execFile` instead. (if you need unlimited buffer, pass in `maxBuffer: Infinity` inside options)