# How to return data from stdout.on

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
function usr_control(type, username, mail, password)
{

    const spawner = require('child_process').spawn;
    const python_process = spawner('python', ['./python.py', type, username, mail, password]);

    python_process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        data.toString();
    }); 
}

usr_control("login", "randomusr", "random@mail.com", "randompass")
```

I want to return data from this function, or return data from stdout.on to variable

I don't know what I can do

Comment: Not to be mean, but this seems like a more general `javascript` question instead of a `python` question.

Comment: Tangentially a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call question.

Comment: There example in nodejs docs seems you missed it. See *3rd* snippet in this [section](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)  (`lsExample` function)

Comment: Since `python_process.stdout` is a Node.js readable you can pass that to `Duplex.toWeb()` and stream the data to a WHATWG `ReadableStream`, as well to get away from the Node.js `on()` eent handler pattern.

Comment: @NoFkGuy See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862197/how-to-use-promisify-with-the-spawn-function-for-the-child-process

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I read from STDIN and child processes with WHATWG Streams.

We get a `readable`, `writable` `TransformStream` pair with `Duplex.toWeb()`.

```
import { spawn } from "node:child_process";
import { Duplex } from "node:stream";

const [command, args] = ["python3", ["./python.py", "login", "randomusr", "random@mail.com", "randompass"]];
const { stdout, stderr } = spawn(command, args);
const { readable, writable } = Duplex.toWeb(stdout);
const data = await new Response(readable).text();
console.log(data);
```

to stream the data from your child process to your `node` script you can do something like this

```
await readable.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).pipeTo(
  new WritableStream({
    write(value) {
      console.log(value);
    },
    close() {
      console.log(`${command} pipe closed.`);
    }
  })
).catch(console.error);
```

Here's you working CommonJS code with the result of the `child_process` stored in a `Promise`, `result`

```
async function usr_control(type, username, mail, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const spawner = require("child_process").spawn;
    const python_process = spawner("python3", [
      "./python.py",
      type,
      username,
      mail,
      password,
    ]);

    python_process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      resolve(data.toString());
    });
  });
}

const response = usr_control(
  "login",
  "randomusr",
  "random@mail.com",
  "randompass",
);
response.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Oh man, that looks so hard, can be something easier?

Comment: I'm getting 'Promise { <pending> } ' in the console

Comment: Are you expecting data to be returned from your Python script? Does you Pythn script exit after `sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk) sys.stdout.buffer.flush()`? Or do you have a `while` loop in your Python code?

Comment: Yes, data will be returned. Python code ends by sys.stdout.flush()

Comment: I'm asking you what your Python code is doing?

Comment: getting data from js, checks if user in database, returns true, false

Comment: Here's working code https://gist.github.com/guest271314/9309337be390860c04abcbb2bfc92d6e

Comment: https://github.com/YuraYarotskyi/data can you create pull request to this code?

Comment: Where are you getting `create_user` from?

Comment: local module in directory

Comment: Kindly include that code in your GtHub repository.

Comment: Okay, it's ready

Comment: Looks like we need `./usr_list.db`, too, to reproduce.

Comment: The issue is in ypur Python code, not the JavaScript code.

Comment: I've added db file, but why problem is in python code, if I tried start another file 
    working.js all works, but I need to return data to variable

Comment: TypeError: Promise.withResolvers is not a function

Comment: What version of `node` are you using? You can replace that with `Promise` constructor.

Comment: node 18.1.0, what is Promise contructor?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise. See updated answer. Keep in mind `response` in the code is a `Promise`.

Comment: oh man, that doesn't work, nothing prints in console